# Formula to calculate/generate gaussian noise?

Tags: noise, gaussian

What is the formula to calculate gaussian noise, given we have variance and mean? I am trying to search google for formula but i am unable to find any much relevant result.  If for example i have mean as "11" and variance as "18".  Then how i can use these two value for calculating/generating a noise signal from gauss distribution??which formula should i use,where i can put these values of variance and mean,and then i will get noise signal

Comment: https://assets.amuniversal.com/321a39e06d6401301d80001dd8b71c47

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MATLAB, you can do it that way:

```
>> nsamples = 1e9;
mu = 11;
sigma_squared = 18;
x = mu + sqrt(sigma_squared)*randn(nsamples,1);
mean(x)
ans =

   10.9998
var(x)   
ans =

   17.9994
```

Edit: link
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/random-numbers-with-specific-mean-and-variance.html

Comment: very nice. But from where did you got this formula?Link?                                                           
                x = mu + sqrt(sigma_squared)*randn(nsamples,1);

Comment: @engr Did you try clicking on and then reading the link?

Answer (score 0):

`tx` = Transmission vector

```
noise=sqrt(sigma2/2)*randn(size(tx));
```

Comment: sigma2? what is it?

Comment: variance of complex noise.

Comment: can you please share link/refrence of this formula??

Comment: no mention/use of mean in this formula? will the factor of mean will be redundant while calculating noise in this case?

Comment: What is transmission vector?how we can get/find its value?

Comment: @engr This was my part of Master thesis, where I did performance analysis of multi-user system (VTC etc.,) Here transmission vector is what each user transmits (after modulation block)...

Comment: @engr you know that matlab has documentation. It would probably pay to *use* the resources given to your. `sqrt` and `randn` are both very well-documented.

Comment: @jomegaA "variance of complex noise", ```noise``` is not complex. You should do ```complexNoise = sqrt(sigma/2)*(randn(size(tx)) + 1j*randn(size(tx)))```.